# redux + react, как контролировать данные?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

Есть redux state, и есть react компонент, мы с помощью connect прокидываем сам state и action для его изменения. Нормально ли ставить value у input в этом компоненте на прямую из redux state? И при onChange вызывать сразу action для изменения? Или все это надо делать через локальный state, а потом уже писать в глобальный redux state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно делать на прямую. Но если надо обрабатывать ошибки ввода то лучше через state компонента